# Audiable pops when switching DC biased audio signal

Tags: audio, dc, bias, zero-crossing, spike

In my previous question, I have asked how to DC bias audio signal for a crosspoint audio switching matrix ([Switch array (crosspoint) and DC biasing of audio signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/433887/switch-array-crosspoint-and-dc-biasing-of-audio-signal)).

I am using the following circuit to achieve this at the moment. I adapted the original circuit from the answer linked above to avoid picking the noise of the power supply and used external bias point generated using TLE2426 (based on the answer from this question: [DC biasing audio signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14404/dc-biasing-audio-signal)).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f32SYe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit works and the audio is properly passing it without any audible frequency range loss, but when turning the switch on or off, there is a loud pop audible on the output connected to the speakers.

I have done simulations of this circuit in LTSpice but there are no big spikes visible at the switching moment. I am a beginner in electronics and don't know where to start looking for the source of poping. I don't own a scope too.

Does anyone have any ideas on what in this circuit could be causing these pops?

**EDIT 1:**

I have added another 10k resistor to the output side. This has helped with the poping a bit. There is still audible pop though, too loud to be ignored.

I have tried lowering 2M2 resistors too, without any improvements.

The updated schematic below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGmOQx.png)</sup>

I have chosen 10k resistors with trial and error as it seemed to my ear that when using 10k resistors, there was less poping than with 100k ones.

I am using these switches in the matrix (see my original question linked above) and if instead just connecting *audio in* to *audio out*, I connect another effect in the matrix, so the switches are *audio in* to *effect in*, and another switch *effect out* to *audio out*, where effect in and out are connected to audio effect, and then I switch **between effect in the chain, and input directly to output, the pops are much louder**.

It might be worth noting that I am using the switch matrix in latched mode, so all the switches are switched at the same time.

Any ideas what could be causing this popping or what should I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loud pop suggests a transient in which a large burst of current is being sunk to, or sourced from, your output (or equivalently, a sudden large voltage swing on the output.) This suggests that, when the output pin is connected or disconnected, the voltage on it suddenly swings. This makes sense for connection, because a floating output pin has nothing keeping it at a particular voltage, and leakage through the capacitor or elsewhere is likely to remove charge from it so that it's no longer at 12V by the time it's reconnected.

For disconnection, though, I'm a little bit puzzled about why there would be a pop. I wouldn't expect one if the switch is just leaving the output floating. Grounding the output would cause a big pop, but I don't see anything about that in the datasheet.

One thing possibly contributing to this is that your resistors to ground are extremely large. The related question you linked:

[DC biasing audio signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14404/dc-biasing-audio-signal?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Has an answer suggesting 10k resistors to ground where you have 2.2M resistors. I would consider lowering those.

I don't know if this is orthodox, but I would consider connecting your DC bias to the output, as well as the input. If the switch is leaving the output floating when disconnected I would expect this to completely solve the problem. If it's grounding it, I would expect this to reduce the problem a bit, but not eliminate it.

Comment: I am using such high resistors to the ground because the input can be high impedance such as guitar pickup. Disconnection pop is not as loud as connection one. So you suggest to add another resistor to the other side of the output capacitors (connect from ouput cap to ground or to bias?) and lower the values of 2M2 resistors?

Comment: Yes, and note that it's only the _output_ side 2M2 resistor to ground that needs to be lowered, you can leave the input one alone, that makes sense about the high impedance input devices.

Comment: Should I connect these additional resistors on the "left" side of the output capacitor to ground or bias? Based on the other answer, my guess would be bias, so both capacitors are on the same voltage levels even when not connected?

Comment: The pop upon disconnect could be happening when the tip/ring/sleeve areas of the audio connector contact the wrong spring-pin on the way out.

Comment: I would say bias, so that the voltage level doesn't change when connected/disconnected, right.

Comment: Your answer did indeed help, but the pops are not completely gone yet. Please see my updated question. Thanks!

Comment: Still thinking about what might be causing the pops, but in the meantime: Would you consider getting a scope? I can strongly recommend the one I own, the Rigol DS1054Z. It's several hundred dollars, but I feel like having a scope is _incredibly_ helpful for stuff like this, so if you plan to do much more electronics work in the future, it will really be worth it.

Comment: Can you measure the DC voltage across the 10k resistor from the 6v rail to the _output_ side, first when the switch is on/closed, and then when it is off/open? In the former case, there should be zero volts across that resistor. In the latter case, hopefully it's still zero, but if it's nonzero that would be interesting (and relevant to the pops.)

Comment: And sorry to do a bunch of comments in a row, but here's another thought: Can you clarify whether the pops happen (1) when switching a channel that is silent, or only when the channel has sound on it during switching; (2) when switching from one input to another (for the sake of a well-controlled experiment, no effects, just switch the output between two inputs, both with the bias voltage applied), or only when switching an input to/from a completely-off state?

Comment: I indeed need to buy a scope, thank you for your recommendation. I have measured the DC voltage across 10k resistors as you suggested and with my multimeter and it was not able to measure any potential difference.

1) when the channel has sound, the pops are indeed louder, but the volume depends on each switch
2) When switching one input to another after I added bias to output, there is some poping but is barely noticeable, whereas if I add effect in the chain, pops are much louder. When switching from a completely off state, the first pop is louder than others.

Comment: 3pC (Charge injection spec from the device datasheet) into meg ohm impedances could well be part of the answer here. Audio switching without pops and clicks is generally a much harder problem then you would expect, to the point that Doug Self devotes a whole chapter in "Small signal audio design" to it. I might suggest a jfet based soft mute at each output to be activated immediately before changing the crosspoint configuration.

Answer (score 0):

A step function will also sound like a pop, you should see a step function in the output because the output cap is not charged prior to the switch being enabled. One solution is to pre-charge the output cap with the same bias. Connect a separate large resistor from the output pin to the same bias voltage used on the input.

Comment: Good point. I will try this indeed.

Comment: I have added 10k bias resistors to the output pins and it did indeed improve the poping issue. There is still some poping though, any ideas what else could be causing this or what to look for? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before you changed your circuit, you were biasing the input of the I2C switch to your reference voltage, but not the output.  This means that with the switch open, the output would drift to wherever it wants -- probably ground.

Then when you switch it on, it was seeing the input, which was biased.

It *should* be enough to bias the outputs to your reference voltage with another \$100\mathrm{k}\Omega\$ resistor.  You may want to try it on one channel to see if it works, then put them everywhere if you find joy.

It sounds like that didn't happen for you.  Probably what's going on is that the fact that the audio is on and getting switched causes the pop.

I've had this same situation happen to me.  The solution for me, back in the days of switches that you had to build up from individual components, was to turn the switch on gradually -- I'd run the gate voltage through an RC circuit, so the turn on event was spread over many audio cycles (something sub-audible, like 50ms, i.e., 1/20Hz is probably good).

This is not something that you can control with a switch operated by I2C -- the answer would either be to briefly mute the audio, then switch, then unmute, or to shop around and see if anyone makes switches specifically for audio that have a gradual switch-over.

Comment: I did this, but the pops are not completely gone yet. Please see my updated question. Thanks!